# I can no longer click the checkboxes in my form?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

While working on a "sign-up" type form with a lot of text and checkbox inputs, I've changed something that no longer allows me to use the mouse to check or uncheck my checkboxes and I'm not sure what.

Oddly (to me anyway), if I tab to any given checkbox and use the space bar, the checkbox will check or uncheck as desired.

I changed the "name" and added a "value" to get my form data to populate correctly in a PHP driven email.  I need those in order for the PHP to work as I have it setup, but I've tried going back and deleting those changes as a test and I'm still not able to use the mouse to check or uncheck even after reverting to the original code which was working.

Am I missing something obvious?  Any suggestions?

The page in question is here: [www.vg4v.com/register-your-guide-service.html](http://www.vg4v.com/register-your-guide-service.html)

My original test-page (where the checkboxes work) is [here](http://www.4sdesignstudio.com/new-projects/volunteer-guides-for-veterans/register-your-guide-service.html)

**The current HTML:**

```
<ul class="button-list">
<!--  Available Activities Checkboxes -->
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Fishing"><label for="fish">Fishing</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Fly-fishing"><label for="fly-fish">Fly Fishing</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Hunting"><label for="hunt">Hunting</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Boat Charters"><label for="charter">Boat Charters</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="HIking"><label for="hike">Hiking</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Rafting or Paddling"><label for="raft">Rafting/Paddling</label></li>
    <li style="width:auto;"><input type="text" name="other_sports" id="other_sports" value="" placeholder="Something we missed?"></li>                                          
</ul>
```

**The Original HTML:**

```
<ul class="button-list">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport" id="fish"><label for="fish">Fishing</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport" id="fly-fish"><label for="fly-fish">Fly Fishing</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport" id="hunt"><label for="hunt">Hunting</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport" id="charter"><label for="charter">Boat Charters</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport" id="hike"><label for="hike">Hiking</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sport" id="raft"><label for="raft">Rafting/Paddling</label></li>
    <li style="width:auto;"><input type="text" name="other-sports" id="other-sports" value="" placeholder="Other services?"></li>                                           
</ul>
```

**My PHP:**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$company = $_POST['company']; 
//top fields
$name = $_POST['name'];   
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$license = $_POST['license'];     
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$website = $_POST['website'];     
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
//checkboxes
foreach($_POST['sport'] as $value) {
$sport_msg .= "$value\n";
}
$other_sports = $_POST['other_sports'];
foreach($_POST['availability'] as $value) {
$availability_msg .= "$value\n";
}
foreach($_POST['season'] as $value) {
$season_msg .= "$value\n";
}
//bottom text boxes
$equipment = $_POST['equipment'];     
$veteranmessage = $_POST['veteranmessage'];


//Validate first
if(empty($company)||empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)||empty($phone)||empty($license)||empty($address)||empty($equipment)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'VGFV Guide Signup';//<== Shows up in the "from" field
$email_subject = "New Guide Signup";//<==  Email Subject

//Begin Email Body

$email_body = "$name has signed up from $company\n\n".
    "Here is their info:\n\n".
    "COMPANY NAME: $company \n\n".
    "GUIDE'S NAME: $name \n\n".
    "PHONE NUMBER: $phone \n\n".
    "EMAIL ADDRESS: $visitor_email \n\n".
    "LICENSE STATE & NUMBER: $license \n\n".
    "HOME BASE: $address \n\n".
    "WEBSITE: $website \n\n".
    "FACEBOOK/SOCIAL MEDIA ADDRESS: $facebook \n\n".    
    "GUIDE SERVICES OFFERED: \n$sport_msg \n\n".

    "AVAILABILITY: \n$availability_msg \n\n".
    "SEASONS: \n$season_msg \n\n".
    "EQUIPMENT PROVIDED: \n$equipment \n\n".
    "NOTE FROM THE GUIDE: \n$veteran-message \n\n".     


$to = "steve@4sdesignstudio.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you assigned any event listener to any of the checkboxes in the client-side code?

Comment: Nope.  There's some quick and dirty form validation, but no event listeners.

Comment: problem's probably in your PHP and are not treating them as an array. You do have form tags, correct?

Comment: I do have form tags =).  I just copy and pasted a snippet.  I'm adding my PHP to my original post now.

Comment: Ok, sorry it's not in your PHP but in your form itself. You need to add the `id`'s back in there for all of them, pretty sure that's what's going on here since it probably has something to do with some JS happening. Unsure but it worked locally for me.

Comment: Of course.  I had added them back in as a test, but I was using the same name as my value instead of what I had used for the labels.  Thanks for the catch.  If you want the points, feel free to answer the question and I'll select it as the answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: I reloaded your page and you added the id's which worked.

Comment: You're welcome, it has been done, *cheers*. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your checkboxes are not "checking" *anymore*, is because you need to add all the `id` tags back in for all your checkboxes.

- This, as per testing locally on my machine and outlined in comments.
- `id="fish"><label for="fish">`

while following the same naming convention for the others.